# Add a third party dll or Library in .net portable library i.e. iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to add a third party dll or Library in .net portable library?

i.e. iTextSharp also keeping in mind itextsharp using system.uri 2.0.0.0 and in .net Portable Library we have system.dll latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in your bin and assign reference from it.